# Plotting route on google map using android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have two android applications. **App1** will find the user location (latitude and longitude values) and it stores it in MYSQL Database. **App2** will retrieve those latitude and longitude values from database and will plot it in google map using :

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + aa1+","+aa2+"&daddr="+temp+","+temp1;
         Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
         intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
         startActivity(intent);
```

Here **aa1** and **aa2** is the first latitude and longitude values and **temp** and **temp1** is the second value from MYSQL DB. When value changes these aa1,aa2,temp,and temp1 value changes accordingly.

Everything works fine. **App2** is getting value from DB and plotting it on map. But when i run the **App1** again the old value stored in DB is not plotting on map. Only the new location values(latitude and longitude) gets plotted on map. But I want the old values to be plotted along with the new values. How to do that. Please help.

Comment: You mean, App1 or App2 are the Activity or a separate application? Which one do you mean?

Comment: @BBonDoo App1 and App2 are seperate applications

Answer (score 1):

I'm no pro, and I probably will say something stupid again and people will vote down my answer, but I think you need to look into your DB. Or can you show us how do you store it, it seems that you are just rewriting the values.

Comment: No its not rewriting the values in DB. When the **App1** runs for the second time the values gets stored only below the values which has been stored previously. Its not rewritting it.